# Why does Elisa fall in love with Amphibian man so fast?

Tags: the-shape-of-water

The fantasy movie, *The Shape of Water (2017)*, has a very short montage about the main character 
as she becomes acquainted with "the monster". The connection 
seems rather forced and I don't really know exactly how much 
time has passed during this montage.

Comment: *Why does Elisa fall in love with Amphibian man so fast?* What is the officially required time? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no clear answer to that. As you say, we don't know how much time has passed during the montage, but given that Strickland's fingers were bit off just before Elisa meets the merman, and they fester during course of the film, I'd say it is no more than a few weeks. This also fits with Giles working on the same ad the whole time. However...

> Elisa clearly has an erotic fascination with water, given that she masturbates in her bath every morning. Also, she has gill-like scars on her neck (which are turned into real gills at the end) and was found as a small child by a river. This suggests that she is actually at least half merfolk herself, though possibly of a different species than the captured merman. This could explain her strong and immediate attraction to him, though sympathy for his plight possibly also played a part.

Comment: You can use `>!` before a block of text to hide it as spoilers.